# How to create a XML file dynamically?

Tags: c#, xml

The problem that I want to solve is that I need to create many XML files.

I know what tags are in which type of XML (examples of XML below) and I know a list of a possible data that could be in each tag.

Someone knows a good way to make that?

I can have XML like the examples below:

XML1:

```
<ID>1</ID>
<name>Maria</name>
<type>client</type>
    <addresses>
        <address>
            <street>Brooklin</street>
            <number>123</number>
        <address>
        <address>
            <street>New York Street</street>
            <number>1000</number>
        <address>
    </addresses>
```

XML2:

```
<name>Paulo</name>
<age>26</age>
<subject>complain</subject>
    <addresses>
        <address>
            <street>Brooklin</street>
            <number>123</number>
        <address>
    </addresses>
```

Comment: The magic word you're looking for is Serialization. You want to have a data structure that matches the XML you want to produce and serialize it to XML.

Comment: As @PhonicUK said - take a look at [Xml Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization)

Comment: @PhonicUK can you put that as an answer?

Comment: @Hatsumi all done :)

Comment: Neither of the two xml files posted are well formed and you may have issue using standard Net Library method to create the files as posted.  An xml file has only one element at the root level.  Both of the xml posted have an array of elements at the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic word you're looking for is Serialization. You want to have a data structure that matches the XML you want to produce and serialize it to XML.

Here's some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization) on doing this in C#.